# Python thread to fill Queue never executes

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm writing a class that maintains a buffer of a dynamically-determined number of values in a queue and refills the queue when it is empty. The constructor of the class looks like this:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self._queue = Queue() # from Queue import queue
    self._queue_capacity = self._INIT_QUEUE_CAPACITY # this is a class constant
    self._fill_queue()
    self._loop()
```

`self._fill_queue` is:

```py
def _fill_queue(self):
    for i in range(self._queue_capacity):
        self._queue.put(1)
        # for this example, it's just a constant put into the queue, but my
        # actual code blocks and generates the required value
```

`self._loop` is:

```py
def _loop(self):
    def fill_queue():
        while True:
            self._queue.join()
            self._fill_queue()
    threading.Thread(target=fill_queue, daemon=True)
```

`fill_queue()` is never called, so when `self._queue.get()` is called after emptying the queue, it blocks indefinitely. Why isn't it being called?

Comment: Is the consumer of this queue calling `.task_done()` for every item retrieved from the queue?  A single failure to do so will cause the `.join()` to hang forever.

Comment: @jasonharper that was my issue! You might want to post that as an answer so that I can mark this as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`threading.Thread` declares the thread, but doesn't start it. You need

```
    threading.Thread(target=fill_queue, daemon=True).start()
```